# Managing 3D resources (samplers, specifically)

Tags: opengl, resources

I've got a question about how to organise my graphics resources/objects.  I'm importing scenes from 3D Studio using AssImp.  At the moment I'm processing the AssImp structures into my own so I can stream them to and from disk more quickly than AssImp can.  Anyway, I'm also processing the scene materials, which gives me a set of choices I'm not too sure how to best handle.

I have the following classes for materials:

*Material*

Contains things like ambient, diffuse colour, specular power and so on, also contains an array of maps, with each slot in the array being a "channel" (i.e. slot 0 is always ambient map, slot 1 diffuse, slot 2 gloss and so on).

*Map*

An instance of a map, with parameters such as wrap mode and a pointer to a texture object.

*Texture*

An OpenGL texture map.

*Sampler*

An OpenGL sampler object.

Now I'm kind-of wondering how I'm going to handle configuring samplers for any given map in a material.  Technically each map can have different sampler parameters.  For example, a sampler can have UV wrap modes, min and max filters and anisotropy.  Some of these parameters are defined in the scene (wrap modes) and others are defined as engine parameters (filtering, anisotropy).

What I'm thinking about doing is creating one sampler object per map (not per texture, remember, a map points to a texture).  Then when I render an object that has a material with map X, it will automatically bind in the sampler for map X to whichever channel it is.  As it's possible there will be thousands of maps, I'm wondering if the corresponding thousands of samplers is a good idea.

Another way of doing it would be to add samplers to my resource dictionary so they can be shared by any map that happens to have the same parameters.

Does anyone have an opinion on how best to manage things like this?

Comment: It should be noted that the word "map" in "texture map" refers to the *mapping* of the texture onto a surface. That is, the texture coordinates (whether static or dynamically generated). The term "texture map" is a misnomer; there's no such animal. So calling it a "map" is wrong.

Comment: That's odd.  I mean a texture is a bitmap, so it kind-of makes sense to call it a texture map.  I shall change its name to *texture* :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not a hard problem.

How many possible different kinds of samplers would you have? If your filtering is a global concept, then the main difference between samplers will be in wrap modes. There are three dimensions of wrapping (S, T, R) and 4 possible wrapping types (CLAMP_TO_EDGE, CLAMP_TO_BORDER, REPEAT, and MIRROR_REPEAT). This gives you a grand total of... 12 possible samplers you could use for normal things.

CLAMP_TO_BORDER requires a border color, so that would require a unique sampler object (unless many textures share the same border color, which is not unreasonable. Black is a popular choice). And if you're doing depth comparison sampling, then you'd need a few more sampler objects.

So just have a sampler object manager that you can ask for a sampler from. You give it some parameters and it regurgitates a sampler. It's either a sampler that exists or one that it created just for you. If you need a unique one (for border colors), then you can ask for a unique one that was given to you. Otherwise, if two people ask for the same sampler, then they get the *same* sampler.